# Python:XML List index out of range

Tags: python, xml

I'm having troubles to get some values in a xml file. **The error is** `IndexError: list index out of range`

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
    <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <infNFe Id="NFe35151150306471000109550010004791831003689145" versao="3.10">
            <ide>
                <nNF>479183</nNF>
            </ide>
            <emit>
                <CNPJ>3213213212323</CNPJ>
            </emit>
            <det nItem="1">
                <prod>
                    <cProd>7030-314</cProd>
                </prod>
                <imposto>
                    <ICMS>
                        <ICMS10>
                            <orig>1</orig>
                            <CST>10</CST>
                            <vICMS>10.35</vICMS>
                            <vICMSST>88.79</vICMSST>
                        </ICMS10>
                    </ICMS>
                </imposto>
            </det>
            <det nItem="2">
                <prod>
                    <cProd>7050-6</cProd>
                </prod>
                <imposto>
                    <ICMS>
                        <ICMS00>
                            <orig>1</orig>
                            <CST>00</CST>
                            <vICMS>7.49</vICMS>
                        </ICMS00>
                    </ICMS>
                </imposto>
            </det>
        </infNFe>
    </NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

I'm getting the values from XML, it's ok in some xml's, those having **vICMS** and **vICMSST** tags:

> vicms = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMS')[i].firstChild.nodeValue
>
> vicmsst = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMSST')[1].firstChild.nodeValue

This returns:

First  returns:

```
print vicms
>> 10.35
print vicmsst
>> 88.79
```

Second **imposto** CRASHES because don't find **vICMSST** tag...

```
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

What the best form to test it? I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree:

**My code**:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import base64,xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

origem = 0
# only loops over XML documents in folder
for file in glob.glob("*.xml"):    
    f = open("%s" % file,'r')
    data = f.read()
    i = 0
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)
    for topic in doc.getElementsByTagName('emit'):
       #Get Fiscal Number
       nnf= doc.getElementsByTagName('nNF')[i].firstChild.nodeValue
       print 'Fiscal Number  %s' % nnf
       print '\n'
       for prod in doc.getElementsByTagName('det'):
            vicms = 0
            vicmsst = 0
            #Get value of ICMS
            vicms = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMS')[i].firstChild.nodeValue
            #Get value of VICMSST
            vicmsst = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMSST')[i].firstChild.nodeValue   
            #PRINT INFO
            print 'ICMS %s' % vicms
            print 'Valor do ICMSST: %s' % vicmsst
            print '\n\n'
            i +=1
print '\n\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several general mistakes in your code.

1. Don't use counters to index into lists you don't know the length of. Normally, iteration with `for .. in` is a lot better than using indexes anyway.
2. You have many imports you don't seem to use, get rid of them.
3. You can use `minidom`, but `ElementTree` is better for your task because it supports searching for nodes with XPath and it supports XML namespaces.
4. Don't read an XML file as a string and then use `parseString`. Let the XML parser handle the file directly. This way all file encoding related issues will be handled without errors.

The following is a lot better than your original approach.

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_text(context_elem, xpath, xmlns=None):
    """ helper function that gets the text value of a node """
    node = context_elem.find(xpath, xmlns)
    if (node != None):
        return node.text
    else:
        return ""

# set up XML namespace URIs
xmlns = {
    "nfe": "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"
}

for path in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    doc = ET.parse(path)

    for infNFe in doc.iterfind('.//nfe:infNFe', xmlns):
        print 'Fiscal Number\t%s' % get_text(infNFe, ".//nfe:nNF", xmlns)

        for det in infNFe.iterfind(".//nfe:det", xmlns):
            print ' ICMS\t%s' % get_text(det, ".//nfe:vICMS", xmlns)
            print ' Valor do ICMSST:\t%s' % get_text(det, ".//nfe:vICMSST", xmlns)

print '\n\n'
```

Comment: thank you for response. good to know what can I improve the code. His approach is much better, I will study it.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one `vICMSST` tag in your XML document. So, when `i=1`, the following line returns an `IndexError`.

```
vicmsst = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMSST')[1].firstChild.nodeValue
```

You can restructure this to:

```
try:
    vicmsst = doc.getElementsByTagName('vICMSST')[i].firstChild.nodeValue
except IndexError:
    # set a default value or deal with this how you like
```

It's hard to say what you should do upon an exception without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, @o_o! I'm starting in python, thanks for the explanation.